# NSInvalidArgumentException - unrecognized selector sent to instance? UITextView / UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uitextview, uipickerview

I am trying to set up a text field that populates a pickerView with the users input. I am getting this error every time I launch the application:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField isEqualToString:]: unrecognized   selector sent to instance.

@synthesize pickerView;
@synthesize textArray;
@synthesize textField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {
    NSLog(@"Current user: %@" , currentUser.username);
}
else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}
    self.textField.delegate = self;

    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
    self.pickerView.delegate = self;

NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:
 UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:
 UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

self.tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                            action:@selector(didTapAnywhere:)];
}

-(void)didTapAnywhere: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) note {
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) note {
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];
}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *) note
{
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:   (NSInteger)component
{
    if ([self.textArray count] == 0)
        return 1;
    return [self.textArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:   (NSInteger)component {
    return [self.textArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:    (NSInteger)component{
    NSLog(@"You selected this: %@", [self.textArray objectAtIndex:row]);
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    [self.textArray addObject:self.textField.text];

    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];

}

- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    [PFUser logOut];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}
@end
```

I'm new to everything, so go easy on me if it's something basic which it probably is. Cheers!

Comment: Are you able to post the whole stack trace for the exception? That line alone doesn't help with the code you posted (as in, do you call `isEqualToString:` anywhere?)

Comment: im not sure if that's the info that helps. I'm literally like only a solid week into this programming thing and know very little about debugging and so on.

Comment: That doesn't help one bit I'm afraid, but your question has been answered below.

Comment: Sure, you can read more about basic iOS debugging at http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be getting this error in

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row  forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.textArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

As you are returning a textfield instead of text(title).

In `viewDidLoad`, change following line:

```
[self.textArray addObject:self.textField];
```

to

```
[self.textArray addObject:self.textField.text];
```

Make sure there is some text, so title is not returned empty. Well what are you actually trying to put in array? Is it text or textfield?

**EDIT**

First what I see is missing **textfield delegate**. Set `self.textField.delegate = self;` in viewDidLoad, so that textFieldDidEndEditing is called. In it, reload pickerview so that it can be correctly populated with current text.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    [self.textArray addObject:self.textField.text];

    [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];

}
```

For picker Title, when there is no data in array, you are returning 1. You should return something as you said in comments.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:   (NSInteger)component {

if(self.textArray.count == 0)
return @"There is nothing";
else
    return [self.textArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Make sure for dismissing keyboard, you should be calling `[self.textfield resignFirstResponder]` when user press "enter key". wire up some method e.g "hidekeyboard" with your textfield for it.

```
-(IBAction) hidekeyboard:(id) sender

{
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope it helps you..!

[image]

Comment: Im trying to take the whatever the user types into the textfield and put in in the pickerView when they tap done. But I can't get data to populate nor can I get it to remove the keyboard. I've updated my original code again to show current state

Comment: But now Im getting an empty array error. So what you are saying is completely correct. I'd like to have the picker display a message to the user when there is no objects in the array.

Comment: Ha, yeah, I was actually able to set that up and get rid of the error. bBut im still not able to populate the picker with text from the textfield and the keyboard is still not disappearing. muh

Comment: @JaredGross as keyboard is not disappearing.Have u set delegate for UITextField.and do regineFirstResponder.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding your text field to textArray, so when you try to use textArray to provide a title in titleForRow:forComponent: you get that error. textArray should contain text, not text fields.

If you want to use the text field to populate the picker, then you should implement the text field delegate method textFieldDidEndEditing: (and maybe others), and add the text field's text to textArray in that method..

Comment: okay, thanks guys! I checked out the website on debugging and followed your advice about implementing a textFieldDidEndEditing delegate. My question now is: how do I add the text field's 'text' to textArray and not the textField?

Comment: @JaredGross, inside textFieldDidEndEditing, you can do [self.textArray addObject:textField.text];

Comment: I added my textFieldDidEndEditing method to my original code that I posted for this question. I am still not getting any data to display in the picker, also not getting the keyboard to disappear when user taps done. again.. I'm sure its's simple but I appreciate the pointers!

Comment: @JaredGross, what you have in there doesn't make sense -- you said in your question that you wanted to populate the picker view from the text field, but now you're making the picker view the input for the text field, which is the opposite (that would populate the text field from the picker's selection). You also shouldn't be instantiating your array again, you already did that in viewDidLoad.